# Using iPhone as a iPod

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch

I was recently given a used iPhone 3G as a gift, and I intend on using it as a iPod. I am told there are ways to do this, but I can not make sense of it. My phone is completely wiped with no sim card. I went to iTunes, but it won't let me activate it without a sim, which I don't have. Is there something I am missing here? Anything I can do to make its use basically an iPod?

Answer (score 3):

You have to activate it once using a matching (netlock-wise) SIM. After activation you can remove the SIM again and use it in WiFi mode.

Comment: Maybe AT&T (or whatever provider your phone is locked to), if they have a local store, will let you use a SIM for this with no charge... call them and see.